# Joomla Plugin onAfterRender

Tags: events, plugins, joomla3.0

How do I make the `onAfterRender` to be called last?
The problem is I wan't to make changes to the `JResponse:getBody()` when everything is all done.
But sadly to say the custom plugin that I created is not being called in last, so after I do my changes to the content there is another plugin that will do its changes, which is not good on my side.
Is there any other way or setup to do, in order my `onAfterRender` get call in last?

[update]
Found and answer from Joomla Forum, but still not working that changing the ordering of plugin to the last, this might work but for some other reason the other plugin is still not following the order.

[image]

As of now, I guess the sequence of constructing the plugin is fine but the event is a bit odd.

[image]
My theory is `Custom Plugin` might have a less process which will call the `onAfterRender` than the `Other Plugin` instead of being in a sequence of `Other Plugin __construct ()Custom Plugin __construct ()Other Plugin onAfterRender ()Custom Plugin onAfterRender ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix the issue by detaching and attaching it on `JEventDispatcher::getInstance();`

```php
/**
     * [onAfterInitialise description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
        $dispatcher->detach($this);
        $dispatcher->attach($this);
    } 

    /**
     * [onBeforeRender description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function onBeforeRender()
    {
        $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
        $dispatcher->detach($this);
        $dispatcher->attach($this);
    }
```

Still I'm in question, hope someone could explain it to me :)